# terraform add route53 record to multiple zones

Tags: terraform, amazon-route53

I want to add the same route53 record into multiple zones, and I can't figure it out.

I'm trying this

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "internal-common-domain" { 
  name = "${var.internal-common-domain}"
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.VPC.id}"
}
resource "aws_route53_zone" "internal-office-domain" {
  name = "${var.env}-${var.internal-common-domain}"
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.VPC.id}"
}
resource "aws_route53_record" "middle-tier-lb" {
  zone_id = "${aws_route53_zone.*.zone_id}"
  name = "middle-tier-elb.${var.internal-common-domain}"
  type = "CNAME"
  ttl = "300"
  records = ["${aws_alb.MiddleTierLoadBalancer.dns_name}"]
}
```

So rather than defining a record resource for each zone I want to add it to I just want to add this record to all the defined zones.

Note the splat in the record for zone_id, doesn't work, Can anyone tell me the most efficient way to do this in terraform ?

Comment: How would this work? You can't put a record called `middle-tier-elb.example.com` in a zone called `staging.example.com`. You would need two separate records here: `middle-tier-elb.example.com` and `middle-tier-elb.staging.example.com`

Comment: OK , I didn't get as far as changing the name line ... but that would need changing too.... infact ..... could I just have a variable that's a list of zone names...then have a single aws_route53_zone resource, and a single aws_route53_record ???

Comment: YAY .. that worked....